# Raised and Slab Foundation in Home

Tags: foundation

I am purchasing a home in Southern California.  During the inspection, we discovered that the home is built on both a raised and slab foundation.

The house was originally built in the late 1940s with a square footage of about 1,400 square feet but was remodeled and doubled in size in 1990. I assumed the slab foundation was the addition which doubled the size of the home but after examining the crawlspace, it appears the raised foundation is too small to have been just the original house. The raised foundation area is only about 1,000 square feet.

Why would the builder have built it this way when they increased the square footage of the home? Are there any issues with having both a raised and slab foundation?

Comment: FYI, I have a '64-built SF home in San Jose which was originally built half crawl-space, half slab. The net effect is that the living room, dining room and kitchen are a step up from the bathroom, family room, laundry room and garage (the rest of the rooms are 2nd floor). I have no idea why this was done but it was definitely original construction.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I assume you haven't had any issues with the foundation? When I asked the home inspector about this, he didn't really give me a straight answer and said I should ask a structural engineer.

Comment: No, no issues and we've been in this house for 25 years. However, we do have pipes going through the slab and I'm hoping this won't turn into an issue.